# Syntax error on INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement (Access SQL)

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, ms-access

I am trying to insert a field '**SID**' Value into **tbl1**, But to get the **SID** It must reference the forename and surname to another table (**tbl2**) to get the **SID**, I then have used the following SQL Statement and subsequent code.

```
    Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO tblPayments (StudentID,Payment,PaymentDate) VALUES (SELECT StudentID FROM tblStudents WHERE Forename = @Forename AND Surname = @Surname , Payment = @SPaid, PaymentDate = @todaysdate)"

    Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand
    With sqlcommand

        .CommandText = sqlquery

        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPaid", Paidtxt.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@todaysdate", Today.Date)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", Forenametxt.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", Surnametxt.Text)

        .Connection = conn

        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    MsgBox("query executed, closing connection")
    conn.Close()
```

Yet, the SQLQuery is giving the error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>        Additional information: Syntax error in query expression 'SELECT StudentID FROM tblStudents WHERE Forename = @Forename AND Surname =
>   @Surname'.

But I can not see what is wrong with the part of the statement that is specified as wrong, can someone tell me where its wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is very evident.  The syntax for `insert . . . select` does not use the `values` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO tblPayments(StudentID, Payment, PaymentDate) 
    SELECT StudentID,  @SPaid, @todaysdate
    FROM tblStudents
    WHERE Forename = @Forename AND Surname = @Surname;
```

Comment: OH Of course, I apologies for the stupidity I rarely use SQL. Thank you for the speed response!